# MYSQL- login Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure

Tags: mysql

```
-bash-4.2$ mysql -u root -pmypassword

Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

the password is correct if i use

```
-bash-4.4$ mysql -u root -p
```

with the same password able to login

the warning message is fine but it has to allow me to login if i give password at command line ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to put password in quotes like:

```
mysql -u root -p"mypassword"
```